# Gitkraken + unity, after push and pull (rebase) source code is strange

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

[image: source image]

[image: scene image]

After pull (rebase), my source code and scene file is strange.

All change code have strange code

I can't open unity scene... help me please

Comment: That just looks like merge conflicts? like you pulled down code after having made changed without pushing them to the repo?

Comment: I did commit -> push -> pull (rebase) in that order.

Comment: maybe merge conflicts. Is there any easy way to solve it?

Comment: I'd recommend using the git CLI unless you have good reasons to use a GUI. It helps to demystify git and to understand how it works. Also don't immediately rebase. You won't be able to tell what is going on. Again, I suggest doing it step by step in the CLI.

Comment: Thank you!! solved merge conflict